# Can we multiply a set of positive integers with a given $N$ to make the tau function injective over that set?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, divisor-counting-function

Consider positive distinct integers $a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_n$. For each positive integer $N$, define the set $$S_N=\{Na_1,Na_2,\dots ,Na_n\}$$

My question is, for any original collection $a_i$, does there exist an $N$ such that $\tau(Na_i)$ is distinct for each $i$? I.e. $\tau$ is injective over $S_N$. Here, $\tau$ denotes the number of divisors function.

For example, if we started with $\{2,3,5,8\}$, we could take $N=45$. I think we might be able to construct $N$ based on the prime factors of $a_i$, or use the Chinese Remainder Theorem somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_j = \prod_{k=1}^K p_k^{e_{j,k}}, \qquad r = 1+\sup_{j,k} e_{j,k},\qquad b = \prod_{k=1}^K p_k^{rk}, \qquad c=\prod_{k=1}^K p_k$$ then $$\tau(a_jbc^x)-\tau(a_ibc^x)=\prod_{k=1}^K (e_{j,k}+rk+x+1)-\prod_{k=1}^K (e_{i,k}+rk+x+1)$$ is a non-zero polynomial in $x$ with only finitely many roots, thus for $x$ large enough 
$$\tau(a_j b c^x)\ne \tau(a_i b c^x)$$

Comment: So once we have that polynomial expression, because it has finitely many roots, taking $x$ above the largest root means that the expression is never $0$ - i.e. no two $a_ibc^x$ are the same. Thanks!

Comment: If you want a concrete expression for $x$ you can replace $b$ by $B=\prod_{k=1}^K p_k^{r^k}$ because then the second leading coefficient of the polynomials are all different and you have a lower bound for the one of $\tau(a_jBc^x)-\tau(a_iBc^x)$ thus from an upper bound for the other coefficients you can upper bound the roots.